# SQL SELECT multiples data from multiples tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

Hy im looking for some help, i have 2 table, tag and user_tag, the tag table store all available tag, the user_tag is the table which store the user choice tag, and i would like to have only the user choice tag and i will display it after.

```
TAG TABLE

ID  TAG

1  Music
2  Sport
3  Dance
4  Cooking
5  Video Games
6  Travel
7  Animals
8  Picture
9  Coding
10 Party

USER_TAG TABLE

id  user_id  tag_id

1    42       9
2    42       10
3    42       5
4    42       4
4    42       7
```

And result should be something like this

```
 user_id  activetag

   42      Party
   42      Coding
   42      Video Games
   42      Cooking
   42      Animals
```

Comment: Exactly, do a `JOIN`! SELECT column1, column2 ... FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.column = table2.column.

Answer (score 0):

Use `join`

```
select user_id, TAG
from USER_TAG u inner join Tag t on u.tag_id=t.ID
```